# Adding each post_type as a class in Wordpress search results

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site with several different post types and although I have separate searches for each section, there's also a main global search that includes results from everywhere. I'm trying to add each post type as a class on the search result page so then I can style them differently depending on what type they are - I don't need to sort them, just want to let people know what section they're from.

Each div on the search page does have post_class, so I just need to get the classes, grab the post_type, append it, and return the classes. I'm trying to do it from a function but I'm obviously missing something.

```
function sg_add_classes($classes){
if ( is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
global $post;
//$myclass = get_post_type( $post->ID);
$myclass = "OMGWHATTHEBLEEP";
$classes[] = $myclass;
}
return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'sg_add_classes', 20);
```

This is where I'm at currently and just trying to add even a hardcoded class isn't working. I'm thinking I need to so something with the loop, but honestly I have no idea what I'm doing anymore. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your search loop look like? You don’t need a function for this.

Comment: Honestly I don't even know. I'm using the Newspaper theme and if I copy the search and archive loop to my child theme and try to modify it, it doesn't recognize any changes. I'm assuming it's because it's using one of the many templates that the theme is installed with. I know on a previous version of my site I had a custom search page (in my child theme) and every time the main theme was updated, my search page quit working. I thought a function would just be less work for me later on.

Comment: Actually you know what, you're right. Just took another look at it and since the last update I AM able to modify the search page. Thank you.